# Valid Vector Space Proof (given v + w = 0 prove w = -v)

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm working through Serge Lang's 'Algebra' and my answers to the proof exercise differ from his but reach the same outcome. I'm not sure if my proofs are invalid or if they are a correct alternative answer.

**Question 1**: Let $V$ be a vector space and $v, w$ two elements of $V$. If $v + w = 0$, show that $w = -v$.

**My Answer Q1:** My Approach uses the two properties of vector spaces: $u + (-u) = 0$, $0 + u = u$ and $u + v = v + u$:
$$ v + w = 0 $$
$$ v + (-v) + w = 0 + (-v) $$ 
$$ 0 + w = 0 + (-v) $$
$$ w = -v$$

**Solution Manual Answer Q1:**
We have $$-w = -w + 0 = -w+(v+w)=v+w-w=v$$

It seems to me that Serge takes the equation $w = -v$ as true and and multiplies both sides by $-1$ yielding $-w = v$ and then substituting $v$ with $0 -w$ from the equation $v + w = 0$ given in the question. Is this not a logical violation?

Comment: No, the books answer does not start from $-w = v$. It starts from $-w$ and obtains $v$ by a series of equalities (read them left to right).

Comment: Specifically, he starts with $-w = -w+0$ (property of $0$), substitutes $v+w$ for $0$ (since $v+w=0$ was given), rearranges the terms (since addition is commutative) and finally uses that $w-w=0$ to  get $v+w-w =v$.

Comment: Ah I can now see what he was doing clearly now, thanks @AlexG.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Is my answer a valid proof?

Comment: It's correct. But apart from the things you mentioned, you also use the commutativity of addition. Well, if we're pedantic, you need some $\iff$s.

Comment: You should also indicate what the relationship is between the lines.

Comment: @DanielFischer good point I had forgotten to include that property. Thanks for the help, I'll also reference the properties I use on each step. What is the best way to lay that out in MathJax?

Comment: You could try this in MathJax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21258 -- not my favorite way to lay this out, but quick and effective.

Comment: @DavidK awesome cheers!